# echo loop inside html tags

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to echo a loop inside another loop inside  html tags anyone can help pls ?
i know theres a parse error but can someone help me figure it out,

also another problem that when i run inside the loop

```
$row['Rating']
```

i get the data from the database but if i put it before in a variable

```
$stars = $row['Rating'];
```

it does not give any value anyone ??

```
<?php
    echo '<td>' . 
    for($x=1;$x<=$stars;$x++) {
        echo '<img src="images/empty-star.png" />';
    }
    if (strpos($stars,'.')) {
        echo '<img src="images/full-star.png" />';
        $x++;
    }
    while ($x<=5) {
        echo '<img src="path/to/blank/star.png" />';
        $x++;
    }
   . '</td>';
?>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: after first echo, tried to change . to ; and last line . to echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo '<td>';
    for($x=1;$x<=$stars;$x++) {
        echo '<img src="images/empty-star.png" />';
    }
    if (strpos($stars,'.')) {
        echo '<img src="images/full-star.png" />';
        $x++;
    }
    while ($x<=5) {
        echo '<img src="path/to/blank/star.png" />';
        $x++;
    }
    echo '</td>';
?>
```

as for your `$row` question, it seem unrelated to the code you supplied. And no, values cannot disappear when assigned.

Comment: its is i need to put the $row from the table in a variable $stars in order to add it to the loop, any suggestion to debug it ?

Comment: Show code where the problem occurs. As far as I know, when `$a = 3` and you do `$b = $a` then `echo $b` gives `3`. Unless you made a mistake which as for now I cannot see